# What are typical wireless security loopholes and how can they be avoided?

Tags: security, wireless-networking, networking

I was wondering if anybody had any thoughts on this, as I recently saw a Verizon DSL network set up where the WEP key was the last 8 characters of the router's MAC address. 
(It's bad enough that hey were using WEP in the first place...)

What are common default security loopholes on wireless routers as they are shipped? How can they be fixed?

Comment: this is better suited to a discussion forum.

Comment: ~quack - That's why it's a community wiki. btw, know of any good forums?

Comment: If you'd change it to: what are typical wireless network security loopholes or something on preventing them, it would be allowed and I would reopen it

Comment: Still seems too broad for a Q/A site like Superuser.  Even forums will tell you to search Google first.  As for forum recommendations: dslreports http://www.dslreports.com/forum/security and ArsTechnica http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewforum.php?f=10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a story a while back about routers having a WEP key that could be derived from the network name and the MAC address. Might of been Thompson, I can't remember.

Relying on MAC address filtering is another bad one - since MAC addresses are transmitted in plaintext, you can just sniff a few packets and pick an address from there. It gets harder when there are multiple networks, and of course you have to wait until that machine is offline (duplicate MAC addresses are not good).